# Data Augmentation with tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I'd like to incorporate Data Augmentation with tf.data into my tf.data pipeline.
For applying data augmentation I'm using TenserFlow's *preprocessing* module and *Sequential* class.
When incorporating a series of data augmentation operations into my tf.data pipeline my dataset type is changing from MapDataset to PrefetchDataset and/or the tensor shape is changing from ...

```
(32, 224, 224, 3)
(32,)
```

to ...

```
(224, 224, 3)
()
```

With that my tensors are in the wrong shape.

**Here is my code:**

```
import numpy as np    
import time
import PIL.Image as Image

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub 

import datetime
import os

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


# Data Preprocessing

normalization_layer = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    layers.Resizing(img_height,img_width)
])
 

# Data Augmentation

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.RandomZoom(height_factor=(0.05), width_factor=(0.05)),
    layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.1),
    layers.RandomContrast(factor=0.1),
])



# incorporate data augmentation into trainingset pipeline

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_batch, labels_batch))

aug_train_ds= (
        train_ds
        .shuffle(batch_size*100)
        .batch(batch_size)
        .map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x, training=True), y))
        .map(lambda x, y: (data_augmentation(x, training= True), y),
            num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
        .cache()
        .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE) 
) 

 # incorporate data augmentation into validationset pipeline

 aug_val_ds= (
    val_ds
    .batch(batch_size)
    .cache()
    .map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y)) 
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE) # Smooth data loader pipeline
)
```

Comment: this kind of looks like it is unbatched now again. Have you tried mapping first and then to batch it?